# CodeIgnitor Error 403 Access forbidden

Tags: codeigniter

I extracted CodeIgnitor to XAMPP's htdocs and when I tried to access index.php like this:

> h t t p://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php

I get the following error message:

> Access forbidden! You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server. Error 403......

How can I troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: please paste errors from log files

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a one-click *AMP stack installer which are generally considered developer tools and hence off-topic for serverFault.

Comment: @kce fair enough, but this is in no way a duplicate of that question. It should have just been marked off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Check your apache error logs to see what apache is saying.  You might need to change to LogLevel error and restart to get enough information.

My guess is that apache runs as www-data (or apache) and you extracted the files as your user with a umask that isn't allowing apache to read it.

```
chmod o+r ci/
```

and see if that helps.  Check the apache error logs if it doesn't and it should give you an idea of why it is having a problem.  Maybe there is a deny block covering that directory for some reason in the configs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the access right in the apache config file like this:

```
<Directory "c:/htdocs">
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```